# How to hide a html element on mouse click only when not using it

Tags: javascript, html, input, mouseover, mouseclick-event

I am creating an online file storage where user can create new files and folders in it. So I added two buttons to create  files and folders. When one of the button is clicked, an input field appears to type a name for the file or folder. Usually the input field is hidden. When user clicks the button, input field is unhidden. Also I need to hide it again if the user clicks somewhere else in the page. Here is the code I've built so far.

```
<head>
<style>
    #divmain{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
    }
    #div1{
        background: antiquewhite;
        width: 30%;
        height: 800px;
        float: left;
    }
    #div2{
        background: black;
        width: 70%;
        height: 800px;
        float: right;
    }
    #input1{
        display:none;
        float:right;
        width:295px;
        height:44px;    
    }
   
</style>
</head>

<body onmousedown="buttonclick1()">
    <h1>cloud file directory</h1><br>

    <div id="divmain">

        <script>        
        function buttonclick1(){
            document.getElementById("input1").style.display="none"
        }        
        </script>

        <div id="div1">
            <button style="height:44px;width:50px;float:left;" onclick="document.getElementById('input1').style.display='block'"><a>Folder</a></button>
            <button style="height:44px;width:50px;float:left;" onclick="document.getElementById('input1').style.display='block'"><a>File</a></button>
            <input id="input1" type="text"><br><br>
            <hr style="border-top: 2px solid;">
        </div> 

        <div id="div2">  
        </div>  
    </div>    
</body>
```

Two buttons are added in div1. I've used a javascript function hide the input field when a mouse click is detected. The code so far is working.

But the problem is, it hides the input field even the mouse click was done in the input field. I need it to be hidden for mouse clicks only outside the input field. I tried using `mouseover`. But don't know how to apply it to here. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, we need an `event` object which has the details regarding the click event. Then we use it to determine whether we should hide/show the input field.

We need to filter out the events based on the element on which the click was made. Here we can use the `id` of the input field to differentiate it from the other clicks. The `target` object contains the details of the element from which the event originated.

Using this it is easy to identify the source element.

```html
<head>
<style>
    #divmain{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
    }
    #div1{
        background: antiquewhite;
        width: 30%;
        height: 800px;
        float: left;
    }
    #div2{
        background: black;
        width: 70%;
        height: 800px;
        float: right;
    }
    #input1{
        display:none;
        float:right;
        width:295px;
        height:44px;    
    }
   
</style>
</head>

<body onmousedown="buttonclick1(event)">
    <h1>cloud file directory</h1><br>

    <div id="divmain">

        <script>        
        function buttonclick1(e){
       if(e.target.id !== 'input1')
            document.getElementById("input1").style.display="none"
        }        
        </script>

        <div id="div1">
            <button style="height:44px;width:50px;float:left;" onclick="document.getElementById('input1').style.display='block'"><a>Folder</a></button>
            <button style="height:44px;width:50px;float:left;" onclick="document.getElementById('input1').style.display='block'"><a>File</a></button>
            <input id="input1" type="text"><br><br>
            <hr style="border-top: 2px solid;">
        </div> 

        <div id="div2">  
        </div>  
    </div>    
</body>
```

Comment: Oo.That's what I was needed. `target.id`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can listen to onblur https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onblur this event is fired when element lost focus

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This one also seems to be useful.

Answer (score 0):

- Use 'blur' with 'addeventlistener'.
  https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_addeventlistener.asp

```html
<script>
    const inputBox = document.getElementById("input1");
    
    inputBox.addEventListener("blur", function (e) {hideMe(e);}); 
    
    function hideMe(event){  
        inputBox.value = '';    // Clears any text within the input box.
    }
</script>
```